# Does dup2 in child process change the fd table in the parent process?

Tags: c, unix

I have a very simple question and just want an answer to reassure whether or not my knowledge of the fork() function and fd table are correct. My question is: perhaps there is a parent process that forks a child. According to my understanding, this child process also has a fd table that is the same as its parent. Suppose I do a dup2 to redirect a fd in the child process; thus, changing the fd table of the child process. Will this change in the child's fd table be also reflected in the parent's fd table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not. The fd table gets inherited from the parent process, but it is private to each process.  - So the child process will start out with a copy of the parent fd table.

Comment: This was precisely what I was looking for. Thank-you for your quick response. Cheers!